# testing factoryGirl factories define rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test my factoryGirl factories:

```
#spec/factories/post.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :post do |p|
  p.title "Title"
  p.body "Body"
 end
end

FactoryGirl.factories.map(&:name).each do |factory_name|
 describe "The #{factory_name} factory" do
  it 'is valid' do
   build(factory_name).should be_valid
  end
 end
end
```

according to [this](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/30994874643/testing-your-factories-first)

But i have this error:

```
in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Factory (NameError)
```

Comment: I just tried the rspec code in one of my model spec files and it worked fine. Does that work for you?? It's not DRY this way, but it might help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

Create a separate file in /spec called factories_spec.rb like this

```
require 'spec_helper'

FactoryGirl.factories.map(&:name).each do |factory_name|
  describe "The #{factory_name} factory" do
     it 'is valid' do
      build(factory_name).should be_valid
     end
  end
end
```

remember to include the require 'spec_helper' line

Comment: ok, it works for me. A question: is better to organize every factoryGirl.define in factories_spec.rb file or is better having a separate file for every FactoryGirl.define ?

Comment: Personally I do separate files, but that's just because those individual files get generated for me when I do 'rails generate model modelName' etc, so I just go with the flow. But this chuck of code is quite nice and DRY, so it makes sense to have it just in one place and have a special one off file for it to cover all factories. It would be interesting to hear other peoples views :)